# How to open links in new tabs only if they contain a specific keyword?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I found a greasemonkey script on the net which opens all the links on a webpage in new tabs.  What I want to do is edit it so that it only opens particular links that contain the word `forum`.

This is the script I am currently using:

```
javascript: (function () {
  {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (i in links) {
      window.open(links[i].href);
    }
  }
})()
```

How can I edit it to do what I want?

Answer (score 55):

That script works on Greasemonkey perfectly, although there are a lot of brackets that can be removed. Here is the version I used:

```
(function(){
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        for (i in links){
            var href = links[i].href;
            if(href.toLowerCase().indexOf('forum') > 0){
               window.open(links[i].href);
            }
        }
    })();
```

Are you sure it isn't working? It may be that your browser is just getting in the way and blocking popups.

Comment: You also should have changed the loop to `for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++){` and a test for existence from indexOf is `!=-1`, not `>0' which will ignore strings that START with what you are looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach would be to query for every anchor tag, place them in an array (as opposed to nodelist), and then conditionally open them in a new window using filter.

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'),function(el){ if(el.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('forum') > -1) window.open(el.href) })
```

Or in a more readable form

```
[].forEach.call(//access array's prototype to call forEach on
 document.querySelectorAll('a')//the nodelist result of all anchor elements
 ,function(el){ //then use that result to iterate through
  if( el.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('forum') > -1 )//check whether or not 'forum' exists
   window.open(el.href) //and if it does open a new tab with the anchors href
})
```

Some references

- slice :
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice
- call :
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call
- querySelectorAll :
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll
- filter :
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Perhaps you could just use `call` directly on `filter` rather than using `slice`; and since you're not using the result of `filter`, you could replace it with `forEach`, for example `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(el) { if (el.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('forum') > -1) window.open(el.href); });` — just a few suggestions!

Comment: @gengkev - Usually I will avoid `forEach` because it doesn't have enough backwards compatibility, but you make a good point because greasemonkey is already running in firefox (which does have support for forEach). Good idea, I will edit it in :)

Answer (score -1):

To test link to contain word `forum` you could use regular expression. So code is something that:

```
function () {
    var pattern = new RegExp('forum');
    var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
        var a = anchors[i];
        if (pattern.test(a.href)){
            window.open(a.href);
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote the userscript which opens external links on any page in new tab.
It has settings to exclude parent, neighbor and child sites links.
Maybe this script or its code will be useful.
It can be installed from one of this repos:
[image]
[image]
[image]
or
by direct link [[image] External link newtaber](https://github.com/almaceleste/userscripts//raw/master/External_link_newtaber.user.js)